# Publishing a book based on long journal article

Tags: journals, copyright, books, publishers

Recently my article has been accepted for future issue in a prestigious journal published by Jhon Wiley and sons. After accceptance of article I received an email from an other publisher based in Germany that they are interested to publish my work in a form of a chapter of a book. They also offer to get roylity money once the book start selling. 
 The copy right statement of the journal, where my article is going to appear, states that  the author can publish a pre-print version on public libraries and can self archive on own website. Moreover, it has a 12 months of emborgo period.
In given circumstances can I publish my work as a chapter of book as well?

Comment: Apart from the things mentioned in the answers: Is this sort of thing common in your field? In my field (math), this would almost certainly be just one more in a long line of almost-scams designed to make some money off other peoples academic work.

Comment: Why don't you ask Wiley?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft my intention is to increase readership of my work. The journal where article is going to appear has much more prestige compare to book publisher. Moreover it will stated in book that this work was published in xyz journal same way we do for the arXiv submission.

Comment: @aparente001 before asking wiley I wanted to if this is a usual case and what are the basic things I may need to settle with them.

Comment: I understand your intention. But if it is not common in your field to be contacted by a publisher (and not for example the author of the book) with requests like this, then one needs to be wary of the deal. This might be completely standard in your field, but at least in mine, it is not.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a lawyer, but John Wiley owns the copyright of your current article, and if you just copy larger parts of it into the book chapter, the german publisher will need to obtain permission from John Wiley (that would already be the case for individual figures) and this can well involve transfer of money. That they allow you to publish a pre-print or put it on your personal website is a concession made to you as a person, but not to other (commercial) publishers.

To avoid any of that you would need to re-write (and ideally expand) the article significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the legal concerns, publishing the same article twice (even when rewritten) is also obviously considered bad academic practice and self plagiarism, unless the book is conceived as a collection of works published elsewhere. In the latter case however the publisher of the book may legally obtain republication rights from the publisher of the journal. Many publishers have a policy which allows issuing republication rights to third parties for a certain fee.

Comment: It's not self-plagirsm the work will be cited as it is originally published in xyz journal same way we do for the arXiv submission.

Comment: This is strongly discipline dependent. In the disciplines where books and book chapters have much weight on a researcher's cv, it's very uncommon to republish earlier published material as book chapters (in my field - archaeology - only very esteemed professors sometimes publish collections of earlier published articles as books late in their career). However this may be different in your field (in this case you'd better specify that in your original question).